# Is there a way to properly switch accounts in Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, user-accounts

So I'm attempting to work with Google Script for some nice planning functionality for myself, and I keep running into [this](https://gyazo.com/2ab5f2d09fe2a243b422cc76aa6e055d). I can work around it by going to the google script webpage directly, but then I run into another problem entirely when I [try to connect it to a sheet](https://gyazo.com/705da476b99ae8e913903af7b1041efd). I assume that the other account that I'm logged into is the owner (because I created both the sheet and the macros for this, which I am trying to add to another sheet) and it [doesn't switch the account](https://gyazo.com/5df402e23ea46f13b98b1d2149d2252d), it just reloads the page. Apologies for the slightly obstructed bview on the last one, my other e-mail has personal info on there that I'd rather not share.

Does anyone know a workaround/solution for any/all of these problems?

Comment: Try a different browser perhaps?

Comment: If the problem is due to being logged in with multiple accounts simultaneously, I recommend you to sign out from all accounts and then to only sign in with the one that is the script owner.